# Is there a shopping cart that integrate into a custom eCommerce site?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, e-commerce, shopping-cart

We are building a custom eCommerce site (for eGov functions like licenses, permits, pay water bill, parking tickets, etc). We envision someone coming in and in one transaction pay their utility bill and parking ticket (or other things they need to pay for). While we don't have the overall flow decided yet, I am curios how others have implemented a shopping cart. Looking at some of the eCommerce packages out there, they are focusing on the whole shopping experience (product to shipping). We really just need the shopping cart as we don't deal with much with a fixed price. For instance, you request a building permit, there maybe a large process before you can actually purchase it.

Do you know of any shopping cart solutions that can integrate into a custom eCommerce site?

I am starting to look at nopCommerce right now, but am open to other options. We are using ASP.NET MVC 3. Another option would be a tutorial on a good shopping cart implementation.

Must-have features are:

- Ability to process transactions with and without a user account.
- Ability to either use the user in the rest of the system or use our own user account setup.
- Integrate with First Data Global Gateway Web Service API.
- Self-hosted and ability to fully integrate into current website design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked at this for reference when i built one before...
http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/other/build-a-shopping-cart-in-aspnet/

Comment: indeed, pity it's not ASP.NET MVC

Answer (score 1):

[KonaKart](http://www.konakart.com/) is excellent for integration - from your ASP.NET world you would probably want to use the SOAP interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

I also started to look at the [MVC Music Store](http://mvcmusicstore.codeplex.com/) example.